# Visual Studio keep asking to install latest silverlight developer runtime, when it is already installed

Tags: silverlight

I developed a Silverlight Application (SL4). The application is already deployed (been working for last 3 months and still working in IIS).

I can't open the solution anymore. VS2010 keeps promting to install the latest version of Silverlight Developers Runtime! Everything is already installed on my work laptop (I developed the application on my work laptop and deployed it). I copied the same solution to my home laptop (which is offline, no internet connection), the solution opens right away in Visual Studio 2010 and eveything works just fine, so there is nothing wrong with the source code (no version conflict, no other smart guessing here).

Is there any Visual Studio or Silverlight update, destroying the development environment, that I am not aware of?

Answer (score 34):

I had the similar problem. Every time I tried to visit a link and install thing I got the same. However, I asked colleagues and they suggested me to install things in the following order:

1.Uninstall everything that has name "Silverlight"

2.Install "Silverlight_5_Toolkit_December_2011.msi"

3.Install "silverlight_5_sdk.exe"

4.Install "Silverlight5_Tools_SP1.exe"

5.Install "Silverlight_Developer_x64.exe"

I had all that packages downloaded in my company, so you will need to find them in internet by yourself. From what I've seen, they are all available. The only matter is direction of installation. This one helped me.

Comment: After trying many different things, it was this particular order that worked for me. THanks

Comment: This helped. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks and it helped me too.. But still keen to know the root cause for this issue? Since it was working fine till 2 weeks back and suddenly it stopped opening silver-light projects .
Any known issues or reasons that we can avoid in future to solve this issue.

Comment: The more up-to-date file list as of 2020:

1. "Silverlight_5_Toolkit_December_2011.1.msi" - from Github;
2. "silverlight_sdk.exe" - from Microsoft Downloads;
3. "Silverlight_Developer.exe" - from Microsoft Downloads;

I couldn't find "Silverlight5_Tools_SP1.exe" since all links are dead, and apparently it's not necessary for the fix.

Answer (score 7):

This is an annoying problem.  Similar to Quarzy, but I didn't have to uninstall VS service packs.  The following worked for me, I'm running Windows 7 Pro x64.

1. Uninstall all "Silverlight..." items in add/remove programs.
2. Install the latest Silverlight SDK, right now it's [Silverlight 5 SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=28359)
3. Install Silverlight developer tools which can be found here [Silverlight download site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/silverlight/bb187452.aspx)

Comment: @Ouarzy doesn't say UNinstall VS service packs, says INSTALL them.

Answer (score 7):

All the solutions above work. Here's the reason why you might mysteriously get the problem when the development environment was set up just fine a few months ago when you had to maintain that *ancient* Silverlight application.

If you have a look at the [Microsoft Silverlight Release history](https://www.microsoft.com/getsilverlight/locale/en-us/html/Microsoft%20Silverlight%20Release%20History.htm) page in *Internet Explorer* (note, it doesn't work in Chrome - go figure). You will see that despite sunsetting Silverlight, Microsoft has been fixing vulnerabilities in it. The latest patch was on June 13 2017.

[Silverlight 5 Build 5.1.50907.0 Released June 13, 2017](https://www.microsoft.com/getsilverlight/locale/en-us/html/Microsoft%20Silverlight%20Release%20History.htm#SL_5_1_50907)

This is well and good, but the patch that gets installed automatically on your development machine is the regular Silverlight runtime, and not the Silverlight *Developer* Runtime.

When you try to install the Silverlight Developer Runtime, it will fail, because you already have Silverlight Runtime installed.

Uninstall Microsoft Silverlight, then install the Developer Runtime, and you should be able to debug your Silverlight apps again.

Answer (score 5):

On "Windows 10" you must change the default browser to IE11 otherwise your LightSwitch app testing in Visual Studio will not work and you go around in circles with the message "Silverlight developer runtime not installed". Edge browser does not support Silverlight.

[Windows 10 System Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AgcUN.png)

Answer (score 4):

if you already have Silverlight Runtime installed.

1. uncheck the silverlight debugger (Properties -> Web -> Debuggers -> 
   Silverlight)
2. rebuild solution
3. check Silverlight debugger and run solution

Answer (score 1):

This is strange as for me this problem should only happen with SL5.
Still my advice would be:

1. Uninstall everything "Microsoft Silverlight" that you have
2. Install every service Pack for VS.
3. Install every Silverlight tools directly form Microsoft Download center (do not trust the direct link from VS, because this link is always for 32bits version and it could be a problem if you work with the 64bits version)

Answer (score 1):

This just started to happen to me (I am using SL4 with VS2010 Pro on XP). I wanted to test a Silverlight 5 app on this computer so I installed SL5 for the first time. Next time I tried to open the SL4 solution on that computer, I got the same message as you so maybe that's what happened on your machine. I pretty much did what Quarzy suggests, but it didn't work. I've not solved this yet...

Edit: Quarzy's solution worked for me on the second try. be meticulous in removing old Silverlight stuff -- I missed the F# Silverlight bit. To restore Silverlight I used 
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=18149 and afterwards, things worked.

I want to add that I messed things up by installing the SL5 plug-in, not development stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need to install x64 based SDK. 
download it from [here](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=229324)

Answer (score 0):

You need to reinstall silverlight

uninstall 'Microsoft Silverlight' 
uninstall 'Microsoft Silverlight 3 SDK'
uninstall 'Microsoft Silverlight 4 SDK' 
uninstall 'Microsoft Silverlight 5 SDK'

install last version + SDK

Answer (score 0):

I had the same, but uninstalling and reinstalling did not help. It appeared that there were wrong installer entries in the registry.

What helped was:

1. Uninstall all Silverlight* from Program and Features
2. Run Piriform CCleaner's Registry function, removing Silverlight* installer
   problems.
3. Reinstall silverlight_sdk
4. Reinstall Silverlight_Developer_x64